# How to append my "advanced-level of economics" to my CV?

Tags: vocabulary

I'm hungarian, and I'm writing my CV in english. I'd like to append my "advanced-level" graduation of economics to it, and I don't know how to formulate it. I'm worried that if I'm not formulating it well, it can come across as a BSc degree or something.

The term in my native language what I'm looking the translation for is "emeltfokú érettségi közgazdaságtanból".

Here's how the hungarian system works: hungarian graduation system on [wiki about hungarian graduating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matura#In_Hungary)

Comment: From the relevant Wikipedia page: ***Matura** is a matriculation examination and can be compared to **A-Level exams**, the Abitur or the Baccalauréat.* But "A-Levels" are part of the ***British*** educational system. I don't know the terminology of the nearest equivalent for ***Americans***.

Comment: You might want to find a common equivalent understood in the West, otherwise you would need to attach a Hungarian graduating system explanation to your CV...

Comment: @AndrewTobilko yeah, that's what I'm looking for

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm American, so I have only a vague understanding of A-Levels based on a bit of Googling, but I honestly don't even think we have anything directly comparable.  The closest thing functionally might be the [SAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAT), but the SAT is a lot more general and less subject-specific.

Comment: @stangdon: I suppose *by definition*, Standard Assessment Tests are supposed to move us towards a unified system. We now have such things in the UK, I believe. But I thought ***High School Diploma*** might be where Americans top out if they don't go on to actual "higher education" (a degree course, which may or may not be comparable even between different *universities*, let along different *countries*).

Comment: There's not really a good equivalent in American English because, except in rare cases like the performing arts or a small handful of subject-focused schools in the largest cities, American secondary school students usually do not have a subject focus the way many European students do.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Yeah, the high school diploma is what you get when you finish high school.  But it's not subject-specific nor do you have to take a specific exam to get it.  Our "SAT" is not the same thing as the UK "Standard Assessment Tests", I don't think; ours is specifically about determining college readiness.  (Theoretically, anyway.)

Comment: So's ours, really. Certainly, back in my day hardly anyone would have stayed at school for an extra couple of years after age 16 to get A Levels unless they were planning to go on to university. But that's shifted somewhat over the past 20-30 years, as governments of all political persuasions have increasingly sought to keep young adults ***in school*** (rather than on the unemployment register).

Comment: Hungarian takes a capital H. There is secondary school education and university-level education. Which is this? I would avoid getting in the AmE and BrE stuff here. "advanced level of graduation" does not exist in English. After university, we do post-graduate degrees (Master's and then Phd).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! This is not a question about the English language. I suggest you delete it and ask  at https://academia.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

I got some help from an English teacher, her answer was: "Advanced level of Economics high-school certificate"